# icon not display in menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to add icon with menu title in android, but it not display with title. Below is my menu.xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/rate_app"
    android:title="Rate App"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_half_24dp"/>
```

I also used `android:icon = "@drawable/ic_star_half_24dp"`, but it didn't display with menu title

Comment: change showAsAction  value from never

Comment: Change the `app:icon` into `android:icon`

Comment: change app:showAsAction="never" to app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750635/icon-in-menu-not-showing-in-android

Comment: I want icon with title on overflow menu

Comment: I have pasted the answer below and please check the following link I have answered in another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645271/popupmenu-not-showing-icons-and-how-to-highlight-popupmenu-item-when-its-opened/28559445#28559445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/A"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_a"
    android:title="Name A"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/B"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_b"
    android:title="Name B"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

      <item
    android:id="@+id/a_More"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_overflow"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="More">
    <menu>

        <item 
            android:id="@+id/C"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_c"
            android:title="Name C"
            app:showAsAction="never" />


        <item 
            android:id="@+id/D"
            android:title="Name D"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item 
            android:id="@+id/E"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_3"
            android:title="Name E"
            app:showAsAction="never" />    


       </menu>
     </item>
  </menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your intended behaviour is to show icon on `toolbar`

`app:showAsAction="never"` should be changed to `ifRoom` or `always`.

If you want to show `icon` on `overflow menu`, then you need to customize the `menu item` and use popup window instead.

Comment: Do you have any formal proof?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using popup menu just copy the below code and run it, you will get icons in popupmenu

PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), view);

try {
    Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
            Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                    .getClass().getName());
            Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                    "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
            setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    popup.getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.publisher, popup.getMenu());

                    //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu:
                                //your function
                                return true;
                                                        default:
                                break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.show();
```